# How to invoke the template function in a loop manner?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, sycl

This question is mostly about the design approach, and I would like to know how to solve such kind of problems in the modern C++ language.

I have a library function that defined like (this is a real code from the compiler):

```
template <info::device param>
typename info::param_traits<info::device, param>::return_type
get_info() const;
```

In order to call this function, I could write something like:

```
some_device.get_info<cl::sycl::info::device::device_type>()
```

where `cl::sycl::info::device::device_type` is an actual parameter.

There a long list of supported parameters and I would like to have a collection of result values (results of different function calls).

At this moment, I could do something like:

```
some_device.get_info<cl::sycl::info::device::param1>()
some_device.get_info<cl::sycl::info::device::param2>()
...
some_device.get_info<cl::sycl::info::device::paramN>()
```

but because this is terrible, I am looking for a better solution in C++ 11/14.

Comment: Since the return type seems to depend on the template parameter (can be different for different parameters), in what collection would you store the returned values?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I would like to convert all return values to std::string first, and store the in a corresponding collection.

Comment: How can `info::device_type` match `<info::device param>` ? Did you mean `info::device::device_type` ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki `device` is probably a regular (unscoped) `enum`.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki device is an enum class, contains supported types.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki that right, thank you. The right way os to use `info::device:device_type`.

Comment: probably something like `template <info::device... Params> std::vector<std::string> f() { return {to_string(some_device.get_info<Params>())...}; }`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It's scoped, that's why I'm asking

Answer (score 1):

With fold expressions no explicit loop (or recursion) is needed. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
void foo(){ std::cout << T{}; }   // just an example

template <typename...Args>
void bar() {
    (foo<Args>(),...);            // call foo for each type in Args
}

int main() {
    bar<int,double,std::string>();
}
```

To have a "collection" of supported types you could use `using collection = std::tuple<int,double,std::string>;`.

Answer (score 0):

For all this kind of code I use Boost.Hana iterating on tuples with a `boost::hana::for_each`, either from user point-of-view but also for SYCL internal implementation.